# How to get the total length light rays has travelled

Tags: rendering, lighting

I would like to get the total length light rays has travelled like in the following discussion.

[How to calculate for every ray the total distance it has traveled from camera to emitter](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81485/how-to-calculate-for-every-ray-the-total-distance-it-has-traveled-from-camera-to?newreg=2b20de0bd5c54c11bed98ce52be4e3f2)

Are there any updates on how to do it differently? Are there other open source Rendering engines that provides the total path length in Blender?